# In The Menagerie Part 1, why is Spock limping?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, spock

Near the end of *The Menagerie Part 1*, in the footage from *The Cage*, there is a scene where the landing party first beams down to Talos IV (about 36'50" on the DVD).

As the group appear walking from behind some rocks, Spock has a noticeable limp. This is not mentioned in the episode.

Is there a reason for this (perhaps something from *The Cage* and omitted in *The Menagerie*) or just Leonard Nimoy carrying an injury?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The injury was scripted rather than real

> **[Leonard Nimoy](https://twitter.com/therealnimoy/status/224212624903114752) -** *Often asked: Why did Spock smile and limp in the first ST pilot? Answer: **Was told to** smile by the director/ to **limp
> by Gene Roddenberry.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/therealnimoy/status/224212624903114752)</sup></sub>

As to *why* Spock was limping;

> **Trivia:** *In case you were wondering why Spock is limping in the scenes
> on Talos IV, the original script for “The Cage” indicated that he’d
> been injured on Rigel VII, in the fight that Pike briefly discusses
> with Dr. Boyce.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek Re-watch: “The Menagerie” Part I](http://www.tor.com/2009/05/12/lemgstar-treklemg-re-watch-the-menagerie-part-i/)</sup></sub>

and

> This 74-page script is very narrative heavy--everything is described
> and explained. Again, very understandable, it was setting the scene,
> describing the Trek universe for the first time.
>
> It is noted that Spock's limp and the bandages on the various
> crewmembers are a result of the recent battle on Rigel VII, thus
> laying to rest all the speculation that Leonard Nimoy was limping
> because of a real life accident.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Cage: Revised Draft](http://www.orionpressfanzines.com/articles/thecage.htm)</sup></sub>

---

From the episode itself;

> **BOYCE:** *Sometimes a man'll tell his bartender things he'll never tell his doctor. What's been on your mind, Chris, the fight on Rigel
> Seven?*
>
> **PIKE:** *Shouldn't it be? My only yeoman and two others dead, **seven injured.***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Menagerie: Transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/1.htm)</sup></sub>